# Is there a useState concept so I can create a service which holds data that is accessed in multiple components?

Tags: scala.js

I have 2 components who want to access the same data.  Instead of each doing an HTTP Request independantly, I wanted to keep the items in parity.  When doing react, we can easily do: `const [ data, setData ] = useState(undefined)` which will allow us to use data in our app and setData to change the global.

I was trying to think of how this might be doable in ReactScala, and Was thinking that there could be some overlap here since you can do something like:

```
useState[A]( data: A ): Pair[A, A=>A] = {
   val d = data
   return d, x => {
     d = x
     return d
   }
}
```

or similar.

I have not seen the documentation on useState in Japgolly as much as defining the property in the component state and then using the state.copy() function to update the value.

The issue which occurred is that to me, state.copy is just 1 component, and wanted to know if there was a way to genericize.

Comment: I am not familiar with react, so, maybe I am missing something obvious to a react pro, but I don't understand how this "concept" is advantageous to just `class Foo[A](private var  d: A) { def data = d; def setData()(d: A): Unit = d = A; }`

Comment: Since I am coupled to ReactScala by Japgolly, Im trying to think of ways to handle 2 things referencing the same data, since they arent in the same Component Hierarchy. >_>

Its weird because I am trying to understand if there is a right way with the Library or if it is moreso a toss up

Comment: Maybe youre way makes sense @Dima.   I was just thinking that in React there is a useState function which returns the data and a function to manipulate it, so i figured there was something similar I would do in this?

I could maybe do it that way, I would just want to instantiate it at the app level and then pass a reference into both

Comment: So, in my example, `new Foo(data)` would be your "function that returns data and the function to manipulate it" ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/japgolly/scalajs-react/blob/master/doc/HOOKS.md

Under the HOOKS file linked above, the top example shows how useState is translated.   I will add it below in case the file is changed or deleted:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function Example() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    document.title = `You clicked ${count} times`;
  });

  const [fruit, setFruit] = useState("banana");

  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
        Click me
      </button>
      <p>Your favourite fruit is a {fruit}!</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Compared to:

```
import japgolly.scalajs.react._
import japgolly.scalajs.react.vdom.html_<^._
import org.scalajs.dom.document

object Example {
  val Component = ScalaFnComponent.withHooks[Unit]

    .useState(0)

    .useEffectBy((props, count) => Callback {
      document.title = s"You clicked ${count.value} times"
    })

    .useState("banana")

    .render((props, count, fruit) =>
      <.div(
        <.p(s"You clicked ${count.value} times"),
        <.button(
          ^.onClick --> count.modState(_ + 1),
          "Click me"
        ),
        <.p(s"Your favourite fruit is a ${fruit.value}!")
      )
    )
}
```